# Update Cursor SQL Statement with If/Then/Else

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, sql-update

I am struggling to figure out how to update with an If/Then/Else scenario. The cursor is grabbing records in the select statement and then compare them to a different table in a linked server. Then if it finds the matching record, update the count from the cursor. If it doesn't find the matching record then insert the row into the table.

The cursor is below and my current update command is just for updating the count where the record found a match.

```
DECLARE @cono INT
DECLARE @repno NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @count INT

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 

SELECT  '1' AS PPCONO,
        b.new_SalesrepId AS PPREP1,
        MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (d.ScheduledStart - c.TimeZoneBias / CAST(24 * 60 AS FLOAT)), 112)) AS PPDATE,
        COUNT(b.new_SalesrepId) AS PPCOUNT,
        MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / CAST(24 * 60 AS FLOAT)), 112)) AS ClosedOn
        FROM ActivityPointerBase AS a
            join SystemUserExtensionBase AS b ON b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
            join UserSettingsBase AS c ON c.SystemUserId = b.SystemUserId
            join ActivityPartyBase AS d ON d.ActivityId = a.ActivityId
                WHERE   b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999'
                        and a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201'
                        and b.new_SalesrepId is not NULL
                        and a.StateCode = '1'
                        and d.ParticipationTypeMask = '9'
                        and CONVERT(varchar(8), a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float), 112) >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,CONVERT(varchar(8), GetDate(), 112)),0) 
                        and CONVERT(varchar(8), a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float), 112) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,CONVERT(varchar(8), GetDate(), 112)),0)
                        /* and CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / CAST(24 * 60 AS FLOAT), 112) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) */
                            group by    b.new_SalesrepId, 
                                        CONVERT(varchar(8), (d.ScheduledStart - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float)), 112)
                                            order by    b.new_SalesrepId ASC;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cono, @repno, @date, @count

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN

UPDATE  [AS400].S062f7ar.APLUS83MDS.PEPAPPTS01
SET     PPCOUNT = PPCOUNT + @count
WHERE   PPCONO = @cono
        and PPREP1 = @repno
        and PPDATE = @date

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cono, @repno, @date, @count

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Not sure how to accomplish the IF/Then/Else scenario in SQL. I did a little research and maybe using Case is the way to go but can you do that with Update commands? I am on SQL 2008.

Comment: Is this a Dynamics CRM database?

Comment: what is primary key column that should be unique in both

Comment: Never ever under any circuymstances use a cursor to do table updates/inserts or deletes. NEVER!!!! very poor practice. In fact you shoudl not ever consider using a cursor at all until you have at least 10 yeaars of DBA experience.

Comment: What do you purpose instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the record exists and if so perform your update, else perform an insert. For example:

```
DECLARE @cono INT
DECLARE @repno NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @date DATETIME
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @closedOn DATETIME

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 

SELECT  '1' AS PPCONO,
        b.new_SalesrepId AS PPREP1,
        MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (d.ScheduledStart - c.TimeZoneBias / CAST(24 * 60 AS FLOAT)), 112)) AS PPDATE,
        COUNT(b.new_SalesrepId) AS PPCOUNT,
        MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), (a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / CAST(24 * 60 AS FLOAT)), 112)) AS ClosedOn
        FROM ActivityPointerBase AS a
            join SystemUserExtensionBase AS b ON b.SystemUserId = a.OwnerId
            join UserSettingsBase AS c ON c.SystemUserId = b.SystemUserId
            join ActivityPartyBase AS d ON d.ActivityId = a.ActivityId
                WHERE   b.new_SalesrepId <> '99999999'
                        and a.ActivityTypeCode = '4201'
                        and b.new_SalesrepId is not NULL
                        and a.StateCode = '1'
                        and d.ParticipationTypeMask = '9'
                        and CONVERT(varchar(8), a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float), 112) >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,CONVERT(varchar(8), GetDate(), 112)),0) 
                        and CONVERT(varchar(8), a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float), 112) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,CONVERT(varchar(8), GetDate(), 112)),0)
                        /* and CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.ActualEnd - c.TimeZoneBias / CAST(24 * 60 AS FLOAT), 112) < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) */
                            group by    b.new_SalesrepId, 
                                        CONVERT(varchar(8), (d.ScheduledStart - c.TimeZoneBias / cast(24 * 60 as float)), 112)
                                            order by    b.new_SalesrepId ASC;

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cono, @repno, @date, @count, @closedOn

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [AS400].S062f7ar.APLUS83MDS.PEPAPPTS01 WHERE PPCONO = @cono and PPREP1 = @repno and PPDATE = @date)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  [AS400].S062f7ar.APLUS83MDS.PEPAPPTS01
        SET     PPCOUNT = PPCOUNT + @count
        WHERE   PPCONO = @cono
            and PPREP1 = @repno
            and PPDATE = @date
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [AS400].S062f7ar.APLUS83MDS.PEPAPPTS01
        (PPCOUNT, PPCONO, PPREP1, PPDATE) 
        VALUES
        (@count, @cono, @repno, @date)  
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cono, @repno, @date, @count    

END    

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: When inserting this into my cursor, the "CLOSE cur" line at the bottom is expecting "CONVERSATION" any ideas?

Comment: @MattWeick I was missing an extra END - to match the BEGIN at the start of the WHILE loop. I have added it now.

Comment: You can't add that extra end because then you're closing out the original BEGIN, it won't keep parsing records in the cursor because FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO is no longer part of the first BEGIN...

Comment: @MattWeick yes, you are correct - it should be after. I have changed that now.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have now and it's saying "Incorrect syntax near 'CLOSE'. Expecting CONVERSATION.

Comment: ok, there are a number of issues with your SQL. Firstly, you are missing `OPEN cur`. Also, there are more columns in your select than variables in your cursor.

Comment: @MattWeick ok, I have updated the answer to include all the working SQL. I have tested using a CRM 2011 database.

Comment: I was missing a BEGIN after your ELSE statement. Thanks for your help on this. Works as designed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MERGE that does update or insert based on condition

```
    MERGE [AS400].S062f7ar.APLUS83MDS.PE. PAPPTS01 T
    USING ( SELECT @cono as     cono, @repno as repno,  @date as    date ) S
    ON 
    T.PPCONO = S.cono
    and T.PPREP1 = S.repno
    and T.PPDATE = S.date
    WHEN MATCHED
    SET     T.PPCOUNT =    T.PPCOUNT + @count
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
    INSERT (PPCONO, PPREP1, PPDATE) VALUES ( S.cono, S.repno,S.date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I havent tested this yet but @Donal answer was suitable for my needs